# How can I integrate an UITableView or UITableViewController into a UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I would like to have an UIPageViewController with several pages where all of them are instances of UITableView or even UITableViewController, but I am a bit lost on how to do this. I have tried adding them from the Interface Builder, but this doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Can you show some code ? What did you try to achieve for now ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have your PageVC and you have connected VCs.  Suggest use standard VCs in preference to TableVCs:

This is how I setup a TableView in a View Controller

**In Storyboard:**

Drag a TableView into the View area.  Select the VC icon (leftmost) in the VC header in the storyboard and in Attributes inspector ViewController layout uncheck Adjust scroll view inserts (this gets rid of some extra space at the top of the tableview.

Click the tableview to select it and cntl-drag from the tableview to again the VC icon and it will offer connect to the TableViewDelegate and to the TableViewDatasource.  Select one and repeat for the other.

Then drag a TableViewCell into the TableView.  Select it and, in the Attributes Inspector, set the identifier to Cell (or whatever but same as in CellForRowAtIndexPath - see below).

Next, in the XCode's top bar click the assistant editor button to get 2 windows.  Have storyboard in left and the View controller in the other.
For simplicity, use a separate Swift file for each VC.
So create an outlet by dragging from the TableView in Storyboard to the VC code call it tableView (at least for now).   We're done with Storyboard so can go back to the Standard Editor and focus on the VC's code.

Next, add the 2 tableview protocols UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource to the VC's source class statement.

Do an Xcode Cmd-S (Save); Shift-Cmd-K (Clean); Cmd-B (build) at this point to give the autocomplete process a nudge.

Lastly, create the 3 main TableView methods - and they should autocomplete:

**NumberOfSectionsInTableView.....**

```
return 1  // for now
```

**NumberOfRowsInSection.....**

```
return array.count   // Assuming your data is in an array called array
```

**CellForRowAtIndexPath.....**
then

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]   //- assuming string array
return cell
```

That should setup your functioning tableview - Repeat for other VC(s).

Tailor accordingly...